# How can I organize Alphanumeric data with Symbol sequentially in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am checking organize my data but this is string data and included sum symbol like (,), % etc.

My code:

```
SELECT F.StatusCb_TEXT
from [E_OpportunityForm_OppForm] F
Inner Join FLOWDOCUMENTS FW ON FW.FILEPROFILEID=F.ID
Inner Join LIVEFLOWS L ON L.ID=FW.PROCESSID
where  OppNo<>''    and L.DELETED=0 and F.StatusCb<>'0.00'
Order by StatusCb_Text ASC
```

Result:

```
(100%) Closed/Won
(15%) Engage/Demo
(30%) Value proposition
(5%) Qualify
(50%) Proposal
(60%) PoC
```

I wanna see:

```
(5%) Qualify
(15%) Engage/Demo
(30%) Value proposition
(50%) Proposal
(60%) PoC
(100%) Closed/Won
```

I found some information related to this issue:

http://www.essentialsql.com/use-sql-server-to-sort-alphanumeric-values/

but it doesn't include any symbol so it gives error when I want to use this code:
 SUBSTRING(Section,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Section),LEN(Section))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may resolve your problem

```
Order by CAST(SUBSTRING(StatusCb_Text,2,CHARINDEX('%',StatusCb_Text)-2) AS INT) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the end of your string properly.

With `PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', )` you're searching the position of the first numeric character. You have to search the position of the last numeric character as well for the substring function. As long as all fields contain the percent character next to the value, you can use the following syntax:

```
SUBSTRING(@Text, 
          PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Text), 
          PATINDEX('%[%]%', @Text) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @Text))
```

or if you know that the column will always start with an opening bracket

```
SUBSTRING(@Text, 2, PATINDEX('%[%]%', @Text) - 2)
```

Cast this to an integer and use it in the `ORDER BY` clause and you will get the desired output.

A better approach would be to have the percentage value properly separated in an own column so that it could be stored as a numeric datatype opposed to a string datatype. But that is only viable if you can alter the table structure without compromising the database.